# Why is mg$\,\cos\theta$ sometimes labeled vertically, and mg$\,\sin\theta$ horizontally?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors

I'm looking at a guide for a physics problem I'm trying to do, and I see this:

[image: confusing axis labeling]

I thought a vector's Y-component was mgsinθ, and in the unit circle, it goes (cos, sin). What's going on?

Comment: It depends on how you define the angle $\theta$.  (BTW the figure is misleading as the projection of $m\vec g$ is visually longer than $mg$.)

Comment: draw an exaggerated ramp (i.e. really shallow slope) to help you visually determine what angle is theta

Answer (score 2):

Rather than giving you a direct answer to *this* question I want to give you a framework for understanding how to resolve all similar problems in the future.

### The root of the problem

In introducing the arithmetic of vectors, we often give student this recipe for finding the components of vector $\vec{v}$ which has magnitude $v$ and angle $\theta_v$:
\begin{align}
v_x &= v \cos \theta_v \\
v_y &= v \sin \theta_v \;
\end{align}
The thing is that there is a precondition on this recipe<sup>1</sup>: **it only works if $\theta_v$ is measured in the usual manner for analytic geometry.**<sup>2</sup>

### A more general approach

When the precondition is not met you have two choices

1. Do some geometry to find the appropriate angle and go with that.
2. Work directly from trigonometry.

#### Working from trigonometry

1. If the vector is axis aligned you can simple write down the components.
2. If the vector is not axis aligned then draw a right triangle around the vector such that (a) the vector is the hypotenuse and (b) the sides are aligned with the axes of your coordinate system.
3. Perform whatever geometry is needed to find the acute internal angles of your new triangle you drew in (2)
4. Select the trig-functions which will yield the (signed) length of the sides (i.e. the components of your vector) from the angles you found in (3).

The existing answers [by D.Ennis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/406864/520) and [by Jasper](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/406862/520) are both explaining the geometry needed to complete step (3)—and that is the part of this procedure that sometimes requires creativity.

---

<sup>1</sup> Which your instructor or text probably mentioned but you almost certainly didn't register as important at the time, because there was too much new stuff being introduced all at once.

<sup>2</sup> Starting from the positive x-axis and increasing toward the positive y-axis.

Comment: can you just please explain to me when to set mgcos of theta to a verticle vector and when not to? thanks

Comment: This *is* that explanation, You—yes, you—have to understand how to decompose vectors. There is no royal road.

Answer (score 0):

**Both** the $mg\cos\theta$  and the $mg\cos\theta$ arrows are way too long in the figure.

The figure is correct with respect to the terms. If you define $\theta$ to be the angle between the slope and the ground, the component perpendicular to the slope is $mg\cos\theta$.

Consider corner cases as a quick verification: for $\theta = 0$, i.e. no slope, all of the gravitational force is acting perpendicular to the slope because $mg\cos\theta = mg \cos(0) = mg$ because $\cos(0) = 1$.

On the other hand, for a vertical slope: $mg\cos\theta = mg\cos(90^\circ) = 0$ because $\cos(90^\circ)=0$.

Comment: presumably one of the arrows is $mg\sin\theta$.

Comment: why is the vector perpendicular to the slope mgcos, even the labeled axis on the right says that perpendicular to the slope is y-axis?

Answer (score 0):

First, understand that the unlabeled angle in your diagram between the $mg\cos\theta$ vector and the $mg$ vector is $\theta$.   Draw a line perpendicular to $mg\cos\theta$ from its tip to the point exactly below $mg$, then extend $mg$ down to that point.   Look at the new triangle you have created. 
  The first line that you drew is the side opposite to $\theta$, so its value is clearly $mg\sin\theta$

Comment: but I thought that in this picture, the x axis is parallel to the slope and thus cosine?

Comment: No.  Trigonometry doesn't care about x and y, it only cares about the hypotenuse, adjacent side, opposite side and included angle.  Yes, you can form triangles in a unit circle centered on the origin of an x-y plane, and then call the sides x's and y's.    But you can also make one in your back yard out of sticks.

Comment: No disrespect intended.  I know it's hard to break an association in your mind once it's formed.  You had a book or an instructor who misled you about this.